# Getting error while using cache-image option for pack build

Tags: java, docker, maven, caching, pack

While I am trying to using --cache-image using below command:

```
pack build -v private.repository/new_image:tag \
--builder cnbs/sample-builder:bionic \
--buildpack samples/java-maven \
--path $PWD \
--cache-image private.repository/cache_image_name:tag \
--publish
```

I am getting below error:

ERROR: failed to create image cache: accessing cache image "private.repository/cache_image_name:tag": parsing auth header '': unknown auth type from header:
ERROR: failed to build: executing lifecycle: failed with status code: 1

Is there something that I am missing here? Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: Can you show how you configured your buildpack?  Reading the error, to me it seems that you have a parameter somewhere called (auth), and the value in it is not known to buildpack.

Comment: Thanks for responding @SusanMustafa. I will check that and get back. But just to point out here the issue only happens when we use --cache-image option. Otherwise normal pack command works fine.